# Metaclass mixing or chaining

Tags: python, metaprogramming, decorator, metaclass, python-decorators

Consider that code:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        def method(self):
            print('generated method call')
        cls.method = method
        super(Meta, cls).__init__(name, bases, attrs)


class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta

    def method(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


def decorator(fn):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('decorator call')
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper

class Decorator(object):
    """Mysterious mixin that should wrap `method` with `decorator`
    at class generation time. And this effect should work on subclasses too!
    """
    def __call__(self, cls):
        cls.method = decorator(cls.method)
        return cls

@Decorator()
class B(A):
    pass

B().method() # outputs "decorated call generated method call"

class D(B):
    pass

D().method() # outputs only "generated method call"
```

Here I have a base class `A`, that has a metaclass that generate `method`.
Than I have `Decorator` class decorator, that adds some effect to the `method` of a decorated class.

It works perfectly on decorated class `B`, but its effect is not inheritable and hence `D` does not inherit that effect.

Thats what I want to achieve - learn how to make inheritable class decorators. Or it can be called as metaclass mixins.

How to achieve this effect? All my tries with metaclasses failed with `metaclass conflict` error.

Comment: brief hint: `class DecoratorMeta(Meta); class B(A): __metaclass__ = DecoratorMeta`

Comment: @o11c What if I have multiple mixins?

Comment: it's perfectly possible to define a new metaclass locally in a function

Comment: @o11c You mean - generate metaclasses?

Answer (score 0):

Both classes `B` and `D` have their own reference to the `method`. That's because you assign it in your `Meta`'s `__init__` method every time new class is creating. You can check it by viewing `__dict__` attribute (like `print(D.__dict__)`).

To achieve inheritance behavior class `D` must not contain their own `method`, in such way it will be taken from parent class `B` which's `method` indeed decorated.

From the said above I propose you the following solution:

```
def decorator(cls):
    def _dec(original_method):
        def _method(*args, **kwargs):
            print('{cls_name} decorated: '.format(cls_name=cls.__name__), end='')
            return original_method(*args, **kwargs)
        return _method
    cls.method = _dec(cls.method)
    return cls


class A():

    def method(self):
        pass


@decorator
class B(A):
    pass


class D(B):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    A().method() or print('A')
    B().method() or print('B')
    D().method() or print('D')
```

The result of the execution of this code will be as following:

```
A
B decorated: B
B decorated: D
```